# Conditional Macros or expanding templates

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, recursion

I have a templated struct like this:

```
class Context {
    template<typename T>
    T construct();
};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct aggregate {
    T construct(Context& ctx) {
        return { std::move(ctx.construct<Args>())... };
    }
};
```

The problem with this is easy to see: When a user requests uses it like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float xyz[3];
} Vector3;

using ConstructVector = aggregate<Vector3, float[3]>;
```

Here an error is generated because this would call the templated function `Context.construct` with `T = float[3]` resulting in a function returning an array. What I thus want is some way to expand `{ std::move(ctx.construct<Args>())... }` to this: `{{ std::move(ctx.construct<float>()), std::move(ctx.construct<float>()), std::move(ctx.construct<float>()) }}` or more general, any array of type `T` (with constexpr size `N`) should be extended to a construct repeating `std::move(ctx.construct<T>())` exactly `N` times and should be wrapped in an additional pair of `{}`.

Is this a wrong approach? Is there another way to initialize an array of values in an aggregate statement?

---

I get the following error from g++ (4.9.1):

```
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/utilitysupplier.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename io::Supplier<T>::item_t io::utility::aggregate_supplier<T, args>::supply(io::Context&) const [with T = Vector3; args = float [3]; typename io::Supplier<T>::item_t = Vector3]':
../test/main.cpp:185:1:   required from here
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/utilitysupplier.hpp:42:37: error: no matching function for call to 'io::Context::construct()'
   return { ctx.construct<args>()... };
                                     ^
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/utilitysupplier.hpp:42:37: note: candidate is:
In file included from C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Context.hpp:141:0,
                 from C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Reader.hpp:13,
                 from C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Environment.hpp:12,
                 from ../test/main.cpp:14:
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Context.tpp:37:28: note: template<class T> typename io::supply_t<T>::type io::Context::construct()
 typename supply_t<T>::type Context::construct() {
                            ^
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Context.tpp:37:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Context.tpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> typename io::supply_t<T>::type io::Context::construct() [with T = float [3]]':
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/utilitysupplier.hpp:42:37:   required from 'typename io::Supplier<T>::item_t io::utility::aggregate_supplier<T, args>::supply(io::Context&) const [with T = Vector3; args = float [3]; typename io::Supplier<T>::item_t = Vector3]'
../test/main.cpp:185:1:   required from here
C:\Users\Carbon\Documents\CreativeWorkspace\EpicRPG\SmartIO/smartio/Context.tpp:37:28: error: function returning an array
```

Comment: Note that unused templated-types (via using) are not actually compiled into the unit so be sure to instantiate a var of type `ConstructVector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating a nested braced-init list is impossible, but generating a flatten one is possible and is suitable for aggregate.

The approach shown below uses C++14 though, with the help of [std::make_index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), but you can implement such a thing in C++11 as well:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct list;

template<class A, class B>
struct merge;

template<class... As, class... Bs>
struct merge<list<As...>, list<Bs...>>
{
    using type = list<As..., Bs...>;
};

template<std::size_t N, class T>
using just = T;

template<class T, class Index>
struct repeat_impl;

template<class T, std::size_t... Ns>
struct repeat_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>
{
    using type = list<just<Ns, T>...>;
};

template<class T, int N>
using repeat = typename repeat_impl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;

template<class T>
struct to_list
{
    using type = list<T>;
};

template<class T, int N>
struct to_list<T[N]>
{
    using type = repeat<T, N>;
};

template<class... Ts>
struct flatten;

template<>
struct flatten<>
{
    using type = list<>;
};

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct flatten<T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename merge<typename to_list<T>::type, typename flatten<Ts...>::type>::type;
};
```

`flatten<float[3], int[2]>::type` will return you `list<float, float, float, int, int, int>`.

Now we can implement `aggregate` as below:

```
struct Context
{
    template<typename T>
    T construct();
};

template<class T, class List>
struct aggregate_impl;

template<class T, class... Args>
struct aggregate_impl<T, list<Args...>>
{
    static T construct(Context& ctx)
    {
        return {ctx.construct<Args>()...};
    }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
using aggregate = aggregate_impl<T, typename flatten<Args...>::type>;
```

Now you can do:

```
using ConstructVector = aggregate<Vector3, float[3]>;
Context ctx;
ConstructVector::construct(ctx);
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3634c656c6bd69)